# Anomaly detection with apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to know if there is an open issue or some related work (publication, platform) that is currently working in an **Anomaly Detection** approach with Apache Flink for a stream data scenario. 
So far I just found the one of [Mux](https://sf-2017.flink-forward.org/index.html%3Fp=1910.html) by Scott Kidder from 2017. Is there something more recent or in working progress? Thanks!

> EDIT

I also found the [flink-htm](https://github.com/htm-community/flink-htm) using the HTM.java framework

Answer (score 0):

I got the help of Flink community with the email list and this are some ideas that they provide me (thanks to Marta):

Flink in these presentations from [Microsoft [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhOZ9Q9_wwI)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhOZ9Q9_wwI) and Salesforce [Salesforce 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4kk1JM8Kcg) at Flink Forward. This [blogpost [3](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-anomaly-detection-with-aws-c237db9eaa3f)](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-anomaly-detection-with-aws-c237db9eaa3f) also describes how to build that kind of application using Kinesis Data Analytics (based on Flink).